# Assets date modal closes info screen w/o saving

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

This is specifically with the Date modal: when I (or the client) go to edit the file information date, we select a day -- and the moment the day selection happens, the file information popup closes without saving the information we'd typed in.

This behaviour seemed to start when we began creating sub-folders for our files, but I don't think that should have affected anything.

Using Assets 2.0.3 on EE 2.5.5

This behaviour shows up both in my Mac Chrome browser and my client's PC (didn't ask her what browser, but I'm going to say she's using IE).

Comment: Hey Lea - I can't reproduce this, and it sounds like a bug report anyway - so can you email support@pixelandtonic.com about it please?  More details, like other potential add-ons, S3 sources or local, etc, would be helpful in that email. Thank you!

Comment: Edited my answer - this bug will be fixed in the next release. :)

Comment: Closing as a bug report!

Answer (score 1):

A day later and now I can reproduce it - not quite sure why I couldn't yesterday.  Reporting this as a bug now.  Thank you Lea!

[Edit] Last edit: this bug is now fixed in Assets 2.0.4. ([Release Notes)](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/releasenotes).  Thank you!